# When returning multiple async tasks how do I know which results came from which task?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I am have the following code to run multiple async tasks and wait for all the results.

```
string[] personStoreNames = _faceStoreRepo.GetPersonStoreNames();    
IEnumerable<Task<IdentifyResult[]>> identifyFaceTasks =
        personStoreNames.Select(storename => _faceServiceClient.IdentifyAsync(storename, faceIds, 1));
      var recognitionresults =
        await Task.WhenAll(identifyFaceTasks);
```

When I get the results how can I get the storename for each task result.  Each array of IdentifyResult will be for a certain storename, but I'm not sure how to end up with my IdentifyResults and the storename they were found in.

Comment: You've probably already https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+whenall+matching+results+to+parameters and know how to get all results... now what exactly you don't know?

Comment: Hi Alexei, I can get the results fine, which is what this link seems to show.  But With the result set, how do I know which results came from which storename?

Comment: I'm not sure if you've seen link to documentation in the search results, probably not - so I've pasted it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but you can use Microsoft's Reactive Framework to make this code a bit neater.

You can write this:

```
var query =
    from sn in _faceStoreRepo.GetPersonStoreNames().ToObservable()
    from irs in Observable.FromAsync(() => _faceServiceClient.IdentifyAsync(sn, faceIds, 1))
    select new { sn, irs };

var result = await query.ToArray();
```

`result` is an array of anonymous variables of `new { sn, irs }`.

One advantage is that you can process the values as they become available:

```
var result = await query
    .Do(x => { /* process each `x.sn` & `x.irs` pair as they arrive */ })
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 5):

As MSDN says use same indexes to get results that you used for parameters.

[WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194874(v=vs.110).aspx)

> If none of the tasks faulted and none of the tasks were canceled, the resulting task will end in the TaskStatus.RanToCompletion state. The Result of the returned task will be set to an array containing all of the results of the supplied tasks in the same order as they were provided (e.g. if the input tasks array contained t1, t2, t3, the output task's Result will return an TResult[] where arr[0] == t1.Result, arr[1] == t2.Result, and arr[2] == t3.Result).